# VLT RCP - process stop caused by NoSuchNodeTypeException

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit

I tried to use vlt rcp (jackrabbit-filevault-3.1.18) in CQ 5.5 and want to use it in AEM6 in future.

But so far it seems not being robust enough because: As soon as it meets a problem on the repository, the whole (recursive) process of node copying is stopped.
Last line in the log:

```
[ERROR] Error during copy: javax.jcr.nodetype.NoSuchNodeTypeException: {http://www.example.com/cmx/1.0}UploadUser
```

Last line a alog of an successful process:

```
Copy completed. <x> nodes in <y>ms. <z> bytes
```

[This question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1229449) in Adobe forum relates to the same topic, but is still unanswered after more than 2 years.

Does anyone have an idea how to force VLT RCP to ignore (and only log) errors?
If not, it's probably the best option to implement this feature by myself ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported. Please feel free to create an issue in the apache jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCRVLT.

however, it is often not possible the recover from an error and subsequent traversal of the sub nodes of the problematic node would result in errors, too.

as a workaround you can exclude problematic paths with the `--exclude` argument.

In you case, it would probably be good to fix the missing nodetype.